# Destructuring object - how to rewrite in a more succinct way

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to know if it is possible to simplify this code and write it in one line (I can use even ES6-7)

```
const { dimensions } = this.state
const { height} = dimensions
console.log(height)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [destructure a nested structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Nested_object_and_array_destructuring).

destructuring inner property - height:

```js
const state = { dimensions: { width: 200, height: 100 }}

const { dimensions: { height } } = state

console.log(height)
```

Destructuring outer and inner property - dimensions and height:

```js
const state = { dimensions: { width: 200, height: 100 }}

const { dimensions, dimensions: { height } } = state

console.log(dimensions)
console.log(height)
```

Comment: `console.log(dimensions)` will have the same output?

Comment: yes, that will correctly output the `dimensions` object

Comment: You can destructure both dimensions and height - see example

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about nested destructuring, that is sexy indeed